# Form boxes are coming up very different in chrome and safari. And difficulty placing an image

Tags: html, css

It took some manipulating to get the username and password form boxes next to eachother. I have it looking good on chrome, but then when I went to safari and firefox, the boxes were at drastically different heights.

The site is www.EpicSwap.com I can't seem to get the code formatted properly Thank you for any help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  If you are after help here its best to post some code and also a more detailed description of your errors.  Use jsfiddle as well for some minimal examples.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making your form a little bit wider, reducing `padding-right` (I took it out completely) on the the `formleft`  element, and making `formright` float left as well. Notice I took out `float:left` on the form as well because it was unnecessary.

Like this:

```
form {
padding-top:6em;
width:450px;
}

#formleft {
float:left;
}

#formright {
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you remove the float and use positioning as shown here

```
#formright 
{
//float: right;
position: relative;
left: 250px;
top: -58px;
}
```

Comment: It's better to use floats than exact positioning like this as it is not dynamic when you zoom in with the browser for example.